# Specifying content type for AMFPHP in cURL

Tags: c, linux, curl, content-type, amfphp

I am using `libcurl` to create an http connection to an `amfphp` server. Do I have to set the content type to any specific format? I noticed there is a option called `AMFPHP_CONTENT_TYPE` in PHP cURL but I couldn't find a corresponding value in `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I have to add `Content-type: application/x-amf` to the `POST` header.